# Reason for ENOMEM failure to create threads?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, 64-bit, pthreads, centos5

I have an application that is using `pthread_create()` and `pthread_detach()` in the main thread and later `pthread_exit()` in the child thread.

After around 54 `pthread_create()` calls that have each been paired with a subsequent `pthread_detach()` and then `pthread_exit()` the `pthread_create()` fails.  It is `ENOMEM` failure "Out of memory".

What might cause `pthread_exit()` to not be freeing up the memory of the old threads and causing my application to leak memory and eventually run out?

This is running on Linux Centos 5 64 bit but a 32 bit built application.

Here is the code to create the thread which calls both `pthread_create()` and `pthread_detach()`.

```
int
_createThread()
{
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  int return_val;

  return_val = setupMutex(_Mtx());

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return return_val;
  }

  return_val = setupCond(_StartCond());

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return return_val;
  }

  return_val = setupCond(_EndCond());

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return return_val;
  }

  return_val = pthread_attr_init(&attr);

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  size_t stackSize = 1024 * 1024 * 64; // Our default stack size 64MB.

  return_val = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stackSize);

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  int tries = 0;

 retry:
  // _initialize() gets called by the thread once it is created.
  return_val = pthread_create(&_threadId, &attr,
                              (void *(*)(void *))_initialize,
                              (void *)this);

  if (return_val != 0) {
    if (return_val == EAGAIN) {
      if (++tries < 10) {
        Exit::deferredWarning(Exit::eagainThread);
        goto retry;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  return_val = pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  return_val = pthread_detach(_threadId);

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Wait for the new thread to finish starting up.
  return_val = waitOnCond(_Mtx(), _EndCond(), &_endCount, 10 /* timeout */, 0,
                          "_createThread-end");

  if (return_val != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

void
_exitThread()
{
  (void) releaseCond(_Mtx(), _EndCond(), &_endCount, "_exitThread-end");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Call **pthread_join** before **pthread_exit** so the thread can cleanup before exiting.

Comment: I see on the man page for pthread_join(): It is unspecified whether a thread that has exited but remains unjoined counts against {PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX}.

Comment: According to http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2004-May/006952.html such threads stay in a "limbo" unless you detach them.

Comment: Oh, but I already had a call to pthread_detach() at their creation, so maybe this is not the issue?

Comment: Indeed if you call detach join should not be necessary.

Comment: Adding the join did not help.  Errno issue is 12 - Out of memory.

Comment: So it definitely leaks, if you can post some code, we might shed some more light into the problem.

Comment: Can you try if ulimit -s unlimited helps?

Comment: @Ismail With ulimit -s unlimited, the running out of memory occurs sooner at around creation of thread number 46 instead of 54.

Comment: For a normally exiting thread if the pthread_detach() has already been called then pthread_exit() is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is in the man page of [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) :

> When a detached thread terminates, its resources are
>   automatically released back to the system without the need for
>   another thread to join with the terminated thread

So if you neither detach it nore join it you loose some resources which finally raises the ENOMEM.

You should either detach the thread or join it from its parent thread.

Comment: In the case of this question, pthread_detach() is being called, so the question remains.

Comment: @WilliamKF In fact I had doubt about how `pthead_detach` was called that's why I specified that it should be done from the parent thread.
I experienced myself this issue and the `pthread_detach` fixed it.

Comment: I've updated the question to show that detach is in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Will, I've deleted my old answer because it seems that I was mistaken. Along this line, I have a question: How did you get `ENOMEM`? Did you check "errno" as I had indicated in my answer? Because `pthread_create` is an exception to the rule, and does not set errno; instead, the error is returned as a result.

Correct way of getting failure reason:

```
int err = pthread_create(...);
if(err)
{
    perror( "Error creating thread" );
    printf( "Error: %s\n", strerror( err ) );
    return false;
}
```

The reason I ask is because `pthread_create` will never fail with ENOMEM! In case of no memory, `pthread_create` will return `EAGAIN`. Refer to http://sourceware.org/ml/glibc-bugs/2007-11/msg00007.html for info on EAGAIN vs ENOMEM

EDIT

Obvious question: the system does have enough free *memory* left, right?

Comment: Yes, the return value from pthread_create() is what I am using for errno, and contrary to the man page, I am getting ENOMEM.  As you may recall, I originally postulated that I was getting EAGAIN, but it turned out to be ENOMEM. Somehow, my threads are leaking memory that is not recovered when they terminate. The process grows in size slowly as the threads are recreated confirming that memory is exhausted.

Comment: ENOMEM is not really from pthread_create, it's from the internal Posix library and has nothing to do with threads per-say. If you're getting ENOMEM, that means you'll probably also get it if you try to create, say, a mutex at that point as well. Basically - you're looking in the wrong place. Your creation of threads and the way they exit is not to blame — you need to look at your memory allocations and make sure you're freeing everything you allocate. The memory grows as threads are created, but not due to the creation; rather, due to what the threads are carrying out.

Comment: If I terminate a thread, is any memory leaked by that thread recovered?

Comment: No. Leaked memory is only released on *process* exit.

Comment: Valgrind reports no leaks:

==25336== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25336==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25336==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==25336== 
==25336== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25336== 
==25336== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25336== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 23 from 11)

Answer (score 0):

call [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_join.html) or alternatively [`pthread_detatch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_detach.html) if joining doesn't work for your use case.

this error occurs because the library is storing the exit codes of all terminated threads, waiting to pass them back to you via `pthread_join()`. alternatively, if you do not care about the thread's exit code, call `pthread_detatch()` after creating it. this tells the API that you do not care about its return code, so it doesn't need to store it.